# Form submit and javascript function calling on submit button click in spring mvc?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, form-submit, spring-form

On the submit button click event, I am calling a js function for getting the user's input and send to the server side for processing. At the same time, I need to submit the form with all the filled data along. I put `<button type="button">` instead `<button type="submit">` as when I put 'type' as submit it gets error. There, the js is functioning finely, but the field values are not fetched by controller method.

How can I do this with only one button ? 
Here is my handler method in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add_package")
    public
    @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView addPackage(@ModelAttribute("newPackage") Package newPackage,
                            HttpServletRequest request) {

        LOGGER.error("package objct {}",newPackage);// here I am getting objects with null values !!

        String s = request.getParameter("test");
        LOGGER.trace("test val = {}", s);

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Package> cats = null;
        String pkgName = newPackage.getPackName();
        try {

           ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ..
            LOGGER.error("error in package add {}", e.getMessage());
        }

        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("add"));
    }
```

Here is the jsp code for button:

```
<form:button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnAddNewPkg" onclick="contentPackge()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
```

Add

Comment: can you share the js function? How you are communicating with controller? using ajax? or directly form submit?

Comment: @user2181397 I am  using ajax. Here it is.
`$.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:8443/admin/packages/add_package",
        data:{"test":JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        // type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
        }
    });`

Comment: try to udpate the url part of the code and put url:"./add_package/"

Comment: @user2181397 It didn't work.. Still I am getting the same error. By the way, currently this ajax function is working well. What I want to do is both calling this function for getting some values  and submitting form on the button click event.

Comment: see you should submit form after the ajax has been successfuly called that is in the success function of ajax you should manually submit the form using jquery.submit() function .other wise it won't work.because it may disrupt the function of ajax .or you could have time delay function after clicking the submit button .

Comment: @RamanaManoj So, do I need to change the button type to `submit`? If you can please show how to use this time-delay function'?

Comment: @SMash show us what is "jsonObj"?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to pass the  `url` as `https://localhost:8443/admin/packages/add_package` instead only `/add_package` will be enough.

Beside you may also need to provide the `url-pattern`

Secondly for ajax response I am not sure why you again need `ModelAndView`. You can explore `redirect` property

If you are using button="submit" , then you need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior. I guess using `button="button"`  will work fine

Comment: This handler method is used for submitting a details of a new item to the database. And why I am returning a ModelAndView is to provide the same view page that maps with "add" url pattern. simply I need to happen both calling this function for getting some values and submitting form on the same button click event

Answer (score 0):

See you should submit form after the ajax has been successfuly called that is in the success function of ajax you should manually submit the form using jquery.submit() function .other wise it won't work.because it may disrupt the function of ajax .or you could have time delay function after clicking the submit button .

this is a nasty way of doing it .i prefer you call the submit function in ajax success and keep button type as button

```
    $( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    event.preventDefault();showloadingif();
    setTimeout(function(){ $("#formId").submit(); }, 3000);         
});
```

Comment: So, do I need to change the button type to submit? If you can please show how to use this time-delay function'?

Comment: Can you elaborate the function  showloadingif(); what does here ?